# refer to name with variable in visual studio 2010 vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to assign text from "comp" in the form "home" to a textbox with the name "d1" in the form "home".
but this needs to be done with a counter in the form "home".
The code is in a module.
What I've tried=

```
home.controls("d" & home.counter).text = home.comp.text
```

I keep getting an error:

```
use the new keyword to create an object instance  ==> the textbox exists in the form
check to determine if the object is null before calling the method ==> the textbox is empty
get general help for this exception
```

Comment: `home` its the current Form?

Comment: `home` It's his name? or variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Controls.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim controls = home.Controls.Find("d" & home.counter, True)
If controls.Length > 0 Then
    Dim txt = TryCast(controls(0), TextBoxBase)
    If txt IsNot Nothing Then
        txt.Text = home.comp.text
    End If
End If
```

However, normally i would not use this approach since it's error-prone. Why don't you provide a public property in the `Home`-form that you can access? This property would get/set the `TextBox`' `Text`.

For example:

```
Public Property HomeCompText As String
    Get
        Return txtHomeComp.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        txtHomeComp.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Now you can use this clear, safe and maintainable code:

```
home.HomeCompText = home.comp.text
```

You could even change the underlying control.